# Difference between pip-sync and pip install -r requirements.txt

Tags: pip, pip-tools

I'm using pip-tools in my project to manage my Python dependencies. What the purpose of `pip-sync`? Looks like it does exactly the same thing as `pip install -r`.

If I have a single `requirements.txt` file, is there any difference between the following two commands?

```
pip-sync
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both commands are used for installing Python packages based on a `requirements` file.

Command `pip install -r requirements.txt` simply installs the packages listed in the file, while `pip-sync` ensures that the installed packages exactly match the contents of the requirements file by adding, upgrading, or removing packages as necessary.